# Scaling NetworkImage view dynamically

Tags: android, layout, android-volley

I am using Volley's NetworkImageView to download images and display them in a dynamic ListView. The app is currently locked in portrait mode, so there's no orientation changes to worry about. It's all working great, except that I am dealing with portrait and landscape images. The landscape images scale perfectly to the window width, but the portrait images scale to their native height (960 pixels) and then don't scale any further to fill the layout. This results in white bars on either side. What I'd like to have is that when I have a portrait photo, its layout scales to the screen width, and ends up taller than a similar landscape photo.

Here's my layout for the NetworkImageView:

```
<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:id="@+id/yarnphoto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

I'd love to hear any thoughts on how to get the view to fill/scale in both directions, depending which is larger.

Comment: I am not sure it is exactly what you want or not but try `android:scaleType="fitXY`

Comment: Unfortunately, that stretches the image without maintaining proportions. What I'd like to do is stretch it to fill the screen, while maintaining proportions.